# An Algorithm for Maximal Correlation

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics, matlab, algorithms

Given a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ over a product space $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$, the *maximal correlation* coefficient is defined as
$$\rho_2(X;Y):=\sup\frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)]}{||f||_2||g||_2},$$ where supremum is taken over all pair of functions $(f,g)$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]=0$ and $f\in L^2(\mathcal{X})$ and $g\in L^2(\mathcal{Y})$.

Renyi showed that that $\rho_2(X;Y)=0$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and  $\rho_2(X;Y)=1$ if there exists a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(X)=g(Y)$ with probability one.

I am looking for an algorithm in R or MATLAB to estimate the maximal correlation for a (discrete or continuous) given joint distribution $P_{XY}$.

Comment: How will the joint distribution be described? Is it perhaps given by a set of data, or is it specified analytically, or maybe in some other way?

Comment: This paper https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~draper/eBay-Google-2013-breiman-friedman-1985.pdf   proposes an estimator.  Another paper is http://stat.fsu.edu/techreports/M835.pdf

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks a lot for these two papers. Are they appropriate for any distributions? Even continuous distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of data, the maximal correlation coefficient can be estimated using the ACE algorithm. The sample ACE algorithm is available in R, under the acepack library. Take a look at this great Quora answer:

https://www.quora.com/Correlation-can-measure-only-the-linear-relationship-between-variables-What-are-the-methods-for-measuring-non-linear-relationships-between-two-variables